# android using jwt authentication right way

Tags: android, jwt, sharedpreferences, encrypted-shared-preference

I am currently building an application that uses JWT authentication. I've build this `rest-api` using `nodejs,mongodb.`

Right now there is not expire duration for access tokens(i know it is not safe, but anyway). What do you think is the best option to store access token in phone? There are several opinions like `AccountManager` and `SharedPreferences`(the one currently i am using). But as we all know they aren't the secure.

Is using `EncryptedSharedPreferences` the right way? or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: EncryptedSharedPreferences should be fine.

Comment: thanks, do you think i need to implement refresh token or is it okay to just use non expiring access token as i will use encrypted-shared-preferences

Comment: depends on the use case. refresh token may be needed for banking applications.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using non-expiring access tokens. Once such a token gets leaked anywhere you will have a vulnerability, someone will be able to use it indefinitely. Access tokens should be short-lived.

Comment: okey, thanks both of you, i will take into consideration